# Exception while passing string to DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Where()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kentico

I'm trying to get nodes like this:

```
DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
.Where("NodeParentID == 25 && NodeLevel == 2")
```

but getting an exception:

> Incorrect syntax near '='.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean
>   isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean
>   shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry,
>   SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText,
>   QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean
>   requiresTransaction)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.HandleError(String queryText,
>   Exception ex)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText,
>   QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean
>   requiresTransaction)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.RunQuery(QueryParameters query)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.RunQueryWithRetry(QueryParameters
>   query, Int32 retryCount)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.ExecuteQuery(QueryParameters query,
>   Int32& totalRecords)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDBInternal()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetResults(IDataQuery query, Int32&
>   totalRecords)    at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB()
>   at
>   CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentQueryProperties.GetDataInternal(IDocumentQuery
>   query, Func`1 baseGetDataMethod, Action`1 setTotalRecords)    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.MultiObjectQueryBase`3.EnsureTypedResult()    at
>   CMS.DataEngine.MultiObjectQueryBase`3.GetEnumerator()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the SQL query being executed.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Kentico or what version you're using, but try `.Where("NodeParentID", QueryOperator.Equals, "25")`. It looks like there's a `.WhereEquals("", "")` syntax also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL syntax is incorrect in your "WHERE" clause. You're trying to use C# syntax in a place where you need to use T-SQL

Incorrect:

```
DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Where("NodeParentID == 25 && NodeLevel == 2");
```

Correct:

```
DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Where("NodeParentID = 25 AND NodeLevel = 2");
```

Answer (score 0):

== is a c# syntax, SQL uses just one =.

You should do your where conditions like this:

```
 .Where("NodeParentID", QueryOperator.Equals, 25)        
    .Where("NodeLevel ", QueryOperator.Equals, 7);
```

Comment: Your code is close, you're missing the .And().

.Where("NodeParentID", QueryOperator.Equals, 25)      
.And()  
    .Where("NodeLevel ", QueryOperator.Equals, 7);

Comment: @BrendenKehren I had that and edited my comment, If you have multiple where conditions like that Kentico will automatically add and.